# Removing border under URL links

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how i can remove the border under the links at my website. It's both irritating and it messes up my design. So I'm asking here instead. I have been searching around Google, but I can only find "How to remove border around image links". 
Can i use css to remove the borders? I have tried "border: solid 0px #000;" 
But it did not work.

So if anyone could help me on this one I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It's not a border, but an underline. This term should yield new results :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to remove the underline, add this to your css :

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked out great! Did not know that it was so easy! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the underline of all the links, you can add:
     a{
        text-decoration:none;
     }

Or if you want to remove the underline of a specified link, then you should create a css class like,

```
.style1{
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Then call this class name with the link like,

```
<a href="#" class="style1">Link</a>
```

It will only remove the underline of that link.